# Another problem in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Given,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{h(2^n x)}{2^n}$$

which is the nowhere differentiable function. Here $h(x)$ is the function defined by:
$$ h(x)=|x| \quad\colon |x|\le1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad h(x+2)=h(x) $$
I am trying to show that $f'(1)$ does not exist.  
 
I have a general idea of how to move through the problem but I am having some trouble with it.  
   
 
I need to find $\,x\rightarrow1\,$ such that $\displaystyle\,\lim_{x\rightarrow m}\frac{f(x_{\small m})-f(1)}{x_{\small m}-1}\,$ does not exist.

Comment: @Hazem Orabi, thanks for the edit. Would you be able to help me out with this problem?

Comment: I think the existing answer is quite okay. Clarifying: 
$$\begin{align} f(1) &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{h(2^n)}{2^n}=\frac{h(1)}{2^0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{h(0+2^n)}{2^n}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{h(0)}{2^n}=1 \\ f'(1) &=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\\&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(1\pm\Delta x)-f(1)}{\Delta x}\\&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{f(1\pm1/2^{\small k})-f(1)}{1/2^{\small k}}\\&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1+k/2^{\small k}-1}{1/2^{\small k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}k\rightarrow\infty  \end{align}$$

Comment: thanks for your answer too

Comment: @HazemOrabi: In fact, the limit doesn't exist even if you permit infinity, because within any neighborhood of $x = 1$, there are points with ratios that are arbitrarily large, positive *and* negative.

Comment: so does that change your solution?

Comment: @jh123: If you're asking me, then no: The point of my (edited) answer is that there is no limit.

Comment: @BrianTung : I just demonstrate another approach that seems more familiar to OP: Set $\,\Delta x = 1/2^{\small k}\,$, Calc $\,f\left(1+1/2^{\small k}\right)\,$, Plug-in and get $\,f'(1)\,$. Nevertheless, I completely agree with your argument.

Comment: @HazemOrabi I have posted another question trying to prove that f(1/2) does not exist

Comment: @HazemOrabi: That seems like we're doing essentially the same thing, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) = f\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right) = 1+\frac{0}{2}
$$

$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right) = f\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right) = 1+\frac{1}{4}
$$

$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right) = f\left(1+\frac{1}{8}\right) = 1+\frac{2}{8}
$$

$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right) = f\left(1+\frac{1}{16}\right) = 1+\frac{3}{16}
$$

$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{32}\right) = f\left(1+\frac{1}{32}\right) = 1+\frac{4}{32}
$$

and in general,

$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right) = f\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right) = 1+\frac{k}{2^{k+1}}
$$

and the result obtains.

Comment: how does this show that the limit does not exist?

Comment: Suppose the limit were $L$.  But this is a sequence of $x$-values that gets arbitrarily close to $1$, and yet for which the ratio takes on the values $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots$, which therefore cannot approach $L$ in the limit.

Comment: should I include a limit calculation in this?

Comment: @jh123: I've just edited my answer.  Hopefully this makes things easier.  We see that no matter how small an interval of $x$ we examine around $x = 1$, we must include some values of $x$ for which the ratio is arbitrarily negatively large and arbitrarily positively large.